# Use one glob.glob instead of multiple glob.glob

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob

I have a folder containing files in different types. I only need to deal with image files (jpg, png, jpeg, JPG, ...). For that, I use `glob.glob` to get only files with 'jpg', 'png', ... extensions.
The problem is that I have to use `glob.glob` many times (as much as the image extensions number) to get all the images:

```
import glob
images = glob.glob('tests/*.jpg') + glob.glob('tests/*.jpeg') + glob.glob('tests/*.png') + glob.glob('tests/*.JPG')
```

Is there a way to use `glob.glob` in a more optimized form (something like `glob.glob('path/*.{'jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'JPG'}`) or is there a simpler function to use it instead of `glob`?

Comment: `glob.glob('tests/*.{jpg, png, JPG}')` returns an empty list

Comment: Sorry, looks like it only support simple shell-style wildcards

Comment: Although you could do something like `[x for x in glob.glob('*') if os.path.splitext(x)[1] in ['.txt', '.jpg', '.png'] ]` :)

Comment: @hansolo this kind of defeat the whole point of glob...

Comment: IIRC glob is case-insensitive, so at the very least you can remove the check for "JPG", since "jpg" will cover that.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Well, yep :)

Comment: @Kevin I'm afraid you dont RC

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, oh, maybe it's OS-specific. I'm on Windows and `glob("*.txt")` returns the same results as `glob("*.TXT")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do complex wildcard globbing like `glob.glob('*.{JPG, png..})` because,
if you take a look at the source code you will see,

```
def glob(pathname):
    """Return a list of paths matching a pathname pattern.
    ....
    """
    return list(iglob(pathname))
```

And then if you find the source of `iglob` you will then see,

```
def iglob(pathname):
    ....
    ....
    dirname, basename = os.path.split(pathname)

    # voila, here, our complex glob wildcard will certainly break, and can't be used :)
```

Therefore, you can only do simple `glob`bing using `glob` :)

Answer (score 4):

Using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

extensions = ['.jpg', '.png', '.jpeg']
images = [x for x in Path('tests').iterdir() if x.suffix.lower() in extensions]
```

Comment: When I run the code you suggested, I got this output: `[PosixPath('tests/a.jpg'), PosixPath('tests/b.jpg'), PosixPath('tests/d.png'), PosixPath('tests/e.jpeg'), PosixPath('tests/c.JPG')]
`, what `PosixPath()` stands for?

Comment: @singrium what about reading the FineManual ? https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: These are described here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pure-paths. They are a platform independent way of representing files.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, I'll take a look at the documentation. Thank you.